# How can I backup my websites files and folders and MySQL database using PHP and send them to an email address in splited 1 MB pieces?

Tags: php, mysql

A quick example would be very helpful.

Comment: why email in chunks? Get gmail and send all at once? also this is not programming related...

Comment: A quick example would be very helpful to me as well ;)

Comment: WHY WOULD YOU DO THAT???

Comment: just copy the files and dump the db. send it in what ever suits you

Comment: @Jakub, how is this not programming related.

Comment: Belongs on either ServerFault or Webmasters.  Agree, off-topic...

Comment: A combination of mysqldump + tar + gzip + split + mail should do the trick. Implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: How IS IT programming related? At what point are you looking for source code / programming logic, etc.  You clearly want server administration help, which IS NOT programming, but administration, or rather trying to make a backup.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool to do what you want : [Website 2 Backup](http://website2backup.com). It is an automatic website files and database backup manager. Archives are encrypted and splitted. You can store on Email, FTP, or locally. Double backup, integrated restoration, and many more.